# Div containing 2 minute tour button not big enough

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

The button `Take the 2-minute tour` is too big for the div containing the text.

[image: bug with the tour button]

Comment: quick solution: a.button { padding: 0em .6em 0em .6em; }

Comment: Perhaps we should make the button even bigger. Maybe then, more users would click on it if we did. ;)

Comment: I feel like it should be full screen, and you're not allowed in until you've spent at least two minutes in the tour :P

Comment: @regal: Better fix: `#herobox-mini #controls a.button { line-height: 1.3 }`

Comment: @IlmariKaronen you copied it from another SE site :)

Answer (score 1):

Seems that it has been fixed:

> [image]